# Flash a Glass Enterprise Edition with a Explorer Edition image

Tags: google-glass

I have a Google Glass Enterprise Edition from Streye (https://streye.com) . Is it possible to flash it with a firmware from https://developers.google.com/glass/tools-downloads/system to be able to use it like an Explorer Edition? Or will I brick my Glass ?

Thank you.

Comment: No, You can't. Because Enterprise edition and Explorer edition hardware are not same also the images. It will damage your device.